# Append same string before every character in another string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, loadrunner

Can we Append same string before every character in another string in LoadRunner?

If I give input like:

```
char *s1 = "Hello";
char *s2 = "\\x";
```

I want to print in output like:
`"\xH\xe\xl\xl\xo"`

Could you please help.

Comment: Hint, your C string is a character array.  Leverage your foundation programming skills to walk the array and build an appropriate string

Comment: Thanks #James, What if my string is like: `char *s1 =  "1.21.32";`
`char *s2 = "\\x";`
and If i want output like below:
`"\x1\x.\x2\x1\x.\x3\x2"`

Comment: Exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *s1 = "Hello";
    const char *s2 = "\\x";
    int s1_len = strlen(s1);
    int s2_len = strlen(s2);
    char *result, *p;

    p = result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (s1_len + s1_len * s2_len + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < s1_len; i++) {
        p = mempcpy(p, s2, s2_len);
        *p++ = s1[i];
    }
    *p = '\0';

    puts(result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile & run:

```
gcc test.c -o test -std=gnu99 && ./test
\xH\xe\xl\xl\xo
```

Comment: Suggest simplification `p = result = malloc(s1_len + s1_len * s2_len + 1);`

Comment: It does not look like `p` is advancing much, only +1 per loop.  Further, not clear what code free's when done.

Comment: mempcpy() returns the pointer to the byte following the last written byte. That's why p is advancing s2_len + 1 per loop.

Comment: c11 7.24.2.1 `void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, ... );` says "The `memcpy` function returns the value of `s1`.", not "pointer to the byte following the last written byte".  Suggest try running this answer's code.

Comment: Thanks #Vianney I am unable to get the required result(`"\xH\xe\xl\xl\xo"
`) by using your logic. Here every time `p` value is equals to `\x follwed by some garbage values` and it is not appending `s1` to `p`. Could you please let me know if am missing something.

Comment: @chux I use mempcpy() not memcpy(). See https://linux.die.net/man/3/mempcpy

Comment: `mempcpy()` is not a standard C library function but a GNU extension.  I took the similar named function as a mis-coding rather than a non-standard function.

Answer (score 0):

A series of `strcpy()`s gets what you need

```
size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
size_t len2 = strlen(s2);

char* res = malloc(len1 * (len2+1) + 1);
res[0] = '\0';
size_t pos = 0;
for (const char *p = s1; *p; ++p, pos += (len2+1)) {
  // append s2 to the string
  strcpy(&res[pos], s2);
  // append the next character
  strncpy(&res[pos+len2], p, 1);
  // add the NUL
  res[pos+len2+1] = '\0';
}
puts(res);
```

This could be done with less code with `strcat` but that would require walking the string on each call.