# Prepend string before each character of another string

Tags: php, string, replace, strsplit, prepend

I have the following code:

```
$target = "abcwa";

for($w = 0; $w <=strlen($target)-1; $w++)
{
  $str = str_split($target[$w],1); //a
  $str_ = $str[$w];
            
  echo "w:";$w;
  echo $str_;
}// end for w
```

It is printing:

```
w:a
Warning: Undefined array key 1 in /in/n705C on line 8
w:
Warning: Undefined array key 2 in /in/n705C on line 8
w:
Warning: Undefined array key 3 in /in/n705C on line 8
w:
Warning: Undefined array key 4 in /in/n705C on line 8
w:
```

Line 8 is `$str_ = $str[$w];`.

However the goal is to print: `w:aw:bw:cw:ww:a`

What is wrong?

Comment: 1. Turn on `display_errors` and turn up `error_reporting` so that you can see all the warnings generated by your code, which are the clues that would help you fix the issues. Eg: https://3v4l.org/n705C 2. `$some_string[$x]` gets the byte at index `$x`, so you don't need `str_split()` at all for this. 3. That is also why the code following `str_split($target[$w])` is breaking, because it returns a 1-byte string, and you're trying to access indexes beyond that on the next line.

Comment: Relate C programming question: [Append same string before every character in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39566680/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would abandon your original code because it is verbose and has multiple failing components.

Instead, just use regex to insert your desired string before each character.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lPQVR))

```
echo preg_replace('/./', 'w:$0', $target);
```

Or

```
echo preg_replace('/(?=.)/', 'w:', $target);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your loop has:

```
$w <= strlen($target) - 1
```

This is more commonly done with:

```
$w < strlen($target)
```

But you don't need any loops at all here. Start by splitting the string into an array of individual letters:

```
str_split($target);
```

This gives you: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'w', 'a']`

Then re-combine that array into a string, but with `"w:"` between each element:

```
echo implode('w:', str_split($target));
```

This gives you:

```
aw:bw:cw:ww:a
```

Then just tack on your leading `"w:"`:

```
echo 'w:' . implode('w:', str_split($target));
```

Which yields:

```
w:aw:bw:cw:ww:a
```

Alternatively, you could add a space to the start of your string, so that the split has one extra character at the start, for the implode to act on:

```
echo implode('w:', str_split(' ' . $target));
```

Which yields:

```
 w:aw:bw:cw:ww:a
```

(Note there's an extra space in the output in this case, if that matters.)